# Elegant way to sum values by time intervals (whilst accounting for missing values)

Tags: r

I'm trying to take something like this

```
df <- data.frame(times = c("0915", "0930", "0945", "1000", "1015", "1030", "1045", "1100", "1130", "1145", "1200"),
                 values = c(1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,3,4))

> df
   times values
1   0915      1
2   0930      2
3   0945      3
4   1000      4
5   1015      1
6   1030      2
7   1045      3
8   1100      4
9   1130      1
10  1145      3
11  1200      4
12  1215      1
13  1245      3
14  1300      4
15  1330      2
16  1345      4
```

And turn it into something like this

```
> df2
  times values
1   0930      3
2   1000      7
3   1030      3
4   1100      7
5   1130     NA
6   1200      7
7   1230     NA
8   1300      7
9   1330     NA
10  1400     NA
```

Essentially, take values measured in 15 minute intervals, and convert them into values measured across 30 minute intervals (summing is sufficient for this).

I can think of an okay solution if I can be certain I have two 15 minute readings for each half hourly reading. I could just add elements pairwise and get what I want. But I can't be certain of that in my data set. As my demo also shows, there could be multiple consecutive values missing.

So I thought some kind of number recognition was necessary, e.g. recognises the time is between 9:15 and 9:30, and just sums those two. So I have a function already called `hr2dec` which I created to convert these times to decimal so it looks like this

```
> hr2dec(df$times)
 [1]  9.25  9.50  9.75 10.00 10.25 10.50 10.75 11.00 11.50 11.75 12.00
```

I mention this in case it's easier to solve this problem with decimal instead of 4 digit time.

I also have this data for 24 hours, and multiple days. So if I have a solution that loops, it would need to reset to `0015` after `2400`, as these are the first and last measurements for each day. A full set of data with dates included could be generated like so (with decimals for times, like I said, either is fine for me):

```
set.seed(42)
full_df <- data.frame(date = rep(as.Date(c("2010-02-02", "2010-02-03")), each = 96),
                      dec_times = seq(0.25,24,0.25),
                      values = rnorm(96)
                      )

full_df <- full_df[-c(2,13,15,19,95,131,192),]
```

The best solution I can come up with so far is a pairwise comparative loop. But even this is not perfect.

Is there some elegant way to do what I'm after? I.e. check the first and last values (in terms of date and time), and sum each half hourly interval? I'm not satisfied with my loop that...

1. Checks first and last date-time value to work out the range of half hours
2. Checks items in order, pair at a time to decide whether or not I have two values that belong to that half hourly period.
3. Sums if I do, places NA if I do not.

Comment: I suggest you to improve your reproducible example by including all cases. For example, a timeslot on midnight as you mentioned in the text.

Comment: Good suggestion @Seymour. I've removed the 2345 timeslot on 2010-02-02 so that the midnight will be an NA on the first day.

Comment: Additionally I'm not too concerned about cases on the end, as I can always do checks to offset whatever solution I go for to start from valid data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm the OP. After a bit of playing I got something which I think is a more elegant solution than the loop I originally had. Decided to post as an answer for discussion. Still wouldn't mind something more elegant still.

Using `full_df` I create an index, which is just all the 15-minute periods I would expect given the days I've been supplied.

```
index <- data.frame(date = rep(seq(full_df$date[1], full_df$date[nrow(full_df)],by="+1 day"),each=96),
                    dec_times = rep(seq(0.25,24,0.25), length(unique(full_df$date)))
)
```

Then I merge this with `full_df` by the two matching columns, and so it keeps values which aren't common (i.e. my missing values)

```
index <- merge(full_df, index, by.y=c("date", "dec_times"), all.y=T)
```

Then I go ahead an create a column which lists what half hour each 15 minute interval belongs to using `plyr`'s `round_any` function

```
index$half_hour <- plyr::round_any(index$dec_times, 0.5, ceiling)
```

Then I use `plyr`'s `ddply` function to sum based on the new `half_hour` column (taking advantage of the fact that anything + an NA is an NA).

```
df2 <- plyr::ddply(index[,c("half_hour","values")], "half_hour", sum)
```

I believe the resulting data frame is exactly what I was after.

```
> df2
   date       half_hour      values
1  2010-02-02       0.5          NA
2  2010-02-02       1.0  0.99599102
3  2010-02-02       1.5  0.29814381
4  2010-02-02       2.0  1.41686296
5  2010-02-02       2.5  1.95570961
6  2010-02-02       3.0  3.59151505
7  2010-02-02       3.5          NA
8  2010-02-02       4.0          NA
9  2010-02-02       4.5 -2.94070834
10 2010-02-02       5.0          NA
11 2010-02-02       5.5 -2.08794703
12 2010-02-02       6.0  1.04275734
13 2010-02-02       6.5  1.46472433
14 2010-02-02       7.0 -2.02043247
15 2010-02-02       7.5 -0.17989752
16 2010-02-02       8.0  1.16028746
17 2010-02-02       8.5  0.42617715
18 2010-02-02       9.0 -1.21205356
19 2010-02-02       9.5 -1.63536660
20 2010-02-02      10.0 -2.37808504
21 2010-02-02      10.5 -0.15505870
22 2010-02-02      11.0  0.03145841
23 2010-02-02      11.5 -0.93546302
24 2010-02-02      12.0  0.63270809
25 2010-02-02      12.5  0.22420168
26 2010-02-02      13.0 -0.46191368
27 2010-02-02      13.5  2.21862683
28 2010-02-02      14.0  0.36631139
29 2010-02-02      14.5  0.76912170
30 2010-02-02      15.0 -2.70820713
31 2010-02-02      15.5 -0.18200408
32 2010-02-02      16.0  1.98156055
33 2010-02-02      16.5  0.57525057
34 2010-02-02      17.0  1.37435422
35 2010-02-02      17.5  1.64160673
36 2010-02-02      18.0 -1.13330533
37 2010-02-02      18.5 -0.33000520
38 2010-02-02      19.0  0.03816768
39 2010-02-02      19.5  1.23194633
40 2010-02-02      20.0 -1.98555720
41 2010-02-02      20.5  1.77062845
42 2010-02-02      21.0 -0.03245631
43 2010-02-02      21.5 -0.58233200
44 2010-02-02      22.0 -0.39989655
45 2010-02-02      22.5  1.75511944
46 2010-02-02      23.0  0.91594245
47 2010-02-02      23.5  2.04145902
48 2010-02-02      24.0          NA
49 2010-02-03       0.5  0.80626028
50 2010-02-03       1.0  0.99599102
51 2010-02-03       1.5  0.29814381
52 2010-02-03       2.0  1.41686296
53 2010-02-03       2.5  1.95570961
54 2010-02-03       3.0  3.59151505
55 2010-02-03       3.5 -1.66764947
56 2010-02-03       4.0  0.50262906
57 2010-02-03       4.5 -2.94070834
58 2010-02-03       5.0 -1.12035358
59 2010-02-03       5.5 -2.08794703
60 2010-02-03       6.0  1.04275734
61 2010-02-03       6.5  1.46472433
62 2010-02-03       7.0 -2.02043247
63 2010-02-03       7.5 -0.17989752
64 2010-02-03       8.0  1.16028746
65 2010-02-03       8.5  0.42617715
66 2010-02-03       9.0          NA
67 2010-02-03       9.5 -1.63536660
68 2010-02-03      10.0 -2.37808504
69 2010-02-03      10.5 -0.15505870
70 2010-02-03      11.0  0.03145841
71 2010-02-03      11.5 -0.93546302
72 2010-02-03      12.0  0.63270809
73 2010-02-03      12.5  0.22420168
74 2010-02-03      13.0 -0.46191368
75 2010-02-03      13.5  2.21862683
76 2010-02-03      14.0  0.36631139
77 2010-02-03      14.5  0.76912170
78 2010-02-03      15.0 -2.70820713
79 2010-02-03      15.5 -0.18200408
80 2010-02-03      16.0  1.98156055
81 2010-02-03      16.5  0.57525057
82 2010-02-03      17.0  1.37435422
83 2010-02-03      17.5  1.64160673
84 2010-02-03      18.0 -1.13330533
85 2010-02-03      18.5 -0.33000520
86 2010-02-03      19.0  0.03816768
87 2010-02-03      19.5  1.23194633
88 2010-02-03      20.0 -1.98555720
89 2010-02-03      20.5  1.77062845
90 2010-02-03      21.0 -0.03245631
91 2010-02-03      21.5 -0.58233200
92 2010-02-03      22.0 -0.39989655
93 2010-02-03      22.5  1.75511944
94 2010-02-03      23.0  0.91594245
95 2010-02-03      23.5  2.04145902
96 2010-02-03      24.0          NA
```

What I like about this solution

- No loops
- Works within the data frame

What I don't like about this solution

- Chunkiness in creating the index

Answer (score 1):

You should check out the [`tibbletime` package](https://business-science.github.io/tibbletime/) -- specifically, you'll want to look at `collapse_by()` which collapses a `tbl_time` object by a time period.

```
library(tibbletime)
library(dplyr)

# create a series of 7 days
# 2018-01-01 to 2018-01-07 by 15 minute intervals
df <- create_series('2018-01-01' ~ '2018-01-07', period = "15 minute")
df$values <- rnorm(nrow(df))
df
#> # A time tibble: 672 x 2
#> # Index: date
#>    date                 values
#>    <dttm>                <dbl>
#>  1 2018-01-01 00:00:00 -0.365 
#>  2 2018-01-01 00:15:00 -0.275 
#>  3 2018-01-01 00:30:00 -1.50  
#>  4 2018-01-01 00:45:00 -1.64  
#>  5 2018-01-01 01:00:00 -0.341 
#>  6 2018-01-01 01:15:00 -1.05  
#>  7 2018-01-01 01:30:00 -0.544 
#>  8 2018-01-01 01:45:00 -1.10  
#>  9 2018-01-01 02:00:00  0.0824
#> 10 2018-01-01 02:15:00  0.477 
#> # ... with 662 more rows

# Collapse into 30 minute intervals, group, and sum
df %>% 
  collapse_by("30 minute") %>%
  group_by(date) %>%
  summarise(sum_values = sum(values))
#> # A time tibble: 336 x 2
#> # Index: date
#>    date                sum_values
#>    <dttm>                   <dbl>
#>  1 2018-01-01 00:15:00     -0.640
#>  2 2018-01-01 00:45:00     -3.14 
#>  3 2018-01-01 01:15:00     -1.39 
#>  4 2018-01-01 01:45:00     -1.64 
#>  5 2018-01-01 02:15:00      0.559
#>  6 2018-01-01 02:45:00      0.581
#>  7 2018-01-01 03:15:00     -1.50 
#>  8 2018-01-01 03:45:00      1.36 
#>  9 2018-01-01 04:15:00      0.872
#> 10 2018-01-01 04:45:00     -0.835
#> # ... with 326 more rows

# Alternatively, you can use clean = TRUE
df %>% 
  collapse_by("30 minute", clean = TRUE) %>%
  group_by(date) %>%
  summarise(sum_values = sum(values))
#> # A time tibble: 336 x 2
#> # Index: date
#>    date                sum_values
#>    <dttm>                   <dbl>
#>  1 2018-01-01 00:30:00     -0.640
#>  2 2018-01-01 01:00:00     -3.14 
#>  3 2018-01-01 01:30:00     -1.39 
#>  4 2018-01-01 02:00:00     -1.64 
#>  5 2018-01-01 02:30:00      0.559
#>  6 2018-01-01 03:00:00      0.581
#>  7 2018-01-01 03:30:00     -1.50 
#>  8 2018-01-01 04:00:00      1.36 
#>  9 2018-01-01 04:30:00      0.872
#> 10 2018-01-01 05:00:00     -0.835
#> # ... with 326 more rows
```

If you're more into videos (< 20 minutes), check out the [The Future of Time Series and Financial Analysis in the Tidyverse](https://www.rstudio.com/resources/videos/the-future-of-time-series-and-financial-analysis-in-the-tidyverse/) by David Vaughan.

Comment: Why some `sum_values` are negative and also not integer as the input data?
Also, how do you deal with timeslot in between midnight?

Comment: Thanks for this, this certainly looks like an elegant way to collapse times if I convert the data type! Do you know how this handles missing values in the series?

Comment: @LachlanO `NA` values will return `NA` unless you modify the `sum` line to include `na.rm = TRUE` -- for example, `summarise(sum_values = sum(values, na.rm = TRUE)`. And if you're dealing with "times" you're going to want to convert :-). If you already have a "time" field, you should be able to use `df <- tbl_time(df, index = your_date_field)`

Comment: There aren't NAs in the original series, only missing times. So for this solution I'd have to fill in the missing values with NAs for this to work? This still sounds like a good solution btw, just trying to understand it fully :)

Comment: @LachlanO If I am understanding your concern correctly, you should not have any issues - that is, any gaps/missing/NA values in the date field would be handled elegantly. The best way to know for sure is to try it out! :) If you run into a different issue, search and/or post a new question.